# How to get selected event in React Big Calendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

```
<BigCalendar
    events={dummyEvents}
    onSelectEvent={event => alert(event)}
    eventPropGetter={eventStyleGetter}
/>
```

After displaying events on `BigCalendar`, I want to know which event is selected. But this snippet just only displays an empty string?

How to get selected event in React Big Calendar?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example please? Also, use console.log over alert

Comment: Yes, console.log worked.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to `alert()` an object. The `onSelectEvent` method gets the full `event` you clicked on `{start, end, allDay, ...rest}`, where `start` and `end` should both be true JS Date objects. And, since you included `onSelectEvent` you must now control `selected` on your calendar.

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

const handleSelected = (event) => {
  setSelected(event);
  console.info('[handleSelected - event]', event);
};
<Calendar
  selected={selected}
  onSelectEvent={handleSelected}
  {...otherProps}
/>
```

Important Note: `selected` must be a reference to an object in your `events` array. The `event`, sent to `onSelectEvent` is a reference, not a copy. If you change your state value later, without updating your `events` array, then RBC won't show those changes.